# is there any way to Underline some text of UILabel and make it Clickable?

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have following text in `UILabel`. I want to underline both text. and give them click event and open related link.

I Agree to the **Terms & Conditions** and **Hotel Booking and Cancellation Policies**

but problem is I couldn't give separate click event for both underlined text.

What is the best way to do that?
I know one option give separate label for all four string. but it is harder to maintain position of all that label for different sizes

Appreciate for help!!!!

Comment: consider using a better UI for a native app, if not, look at attributed string with links

Answer (score 0):

take a look of this library Might be it will help you: https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to change the UI design. A possible work around I found is add UILabel below this text label/button with text contains a number of under scores(_) and pin it with auto layout. N.B: It's never ever a good practice at all.
[image]